# How to get details of rows whose images are missing in the uploads

Tags: sql, codeigniter-3

i have done image upload for a registration functionality.. the registrations are over... now the image names are in database.. but in uploads folder, some images are missing. Now what I want is to get the report of the rows whose images are missing in the folder.

i want the report of the rows whose images are missing in the folder

Answer (score 0):

It will help full for you.

Create a function like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FileExists(@path varchar(512))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @result INT
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
     RETURN cast(@result as bit)
END;
GO
```

Edit your table and add a computed column (IsExists BIT). Set the expression to:

```
dbo.fn_FileExists(filepath)
```

Then just select:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable where IsExists = 1
```

Update:

To use the function outside a computed column:

```
select id, filename, dbo.fn_FileExists(filename) as IsExists
from dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: thank you for replying...    its throwing error
Error Code: 1064

Comment: <e>Query: CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FileExists(path varchar(512)) RETURNS BIT AS BEGIN DECLARE @result INT EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist pat...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'path varchar(512))
RETURNS BIT